# Exoplayer for video view scroll Play and pause

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview, adapter, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using exoplayer in recycleview for playing video but when i scroll that view the video is not stop and play automatically.
and also all video will we played if I play manually .
I tried lot of to achieve this but i didn't  get Proper solutions.
Can anyone please give me some solution .

I am using following things.

1. Fragment for load the recycleView
2. Adapter for showing all the data.
3. Model Class